# Redux & React Native component connect: this.props is undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, undefined

I am trying to access the name field as defined in the initial state of my reducer. At the moment, this.props is returning undefined.

My reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    name: "Test"
}

const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      default:
        return state
    }
};

export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
});
```

The component being rendered (this logs "Props: undefined"):

```
const AddName = ({ navigation }) => {

    ...

    console.log("Props: ", this.props)

    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    )
}

mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
      user : state.user
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AddName)
```

Creating the redux store and provider:

```
...
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './src/reducers/userReducer';

const store = createStore(reducer)

const AppContainer = () => 
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
    </Provider>


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppContainer);
```

Comment: It's a functional component, there is no `this` but you can access props - change `const AddName = ({ navigation }) => {` to `const AddName = (props) => {` and then access the `props` object - otherwise you are destructuring the props in the function definition.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Comment: @madebydavid Doh, thank you! I ended up using the new React Hooks in react-redux. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/using-redux-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a functional component and `this` keyword doesnt apply to functional components, rather it applies it to class Components.

Change your component as below :

```
class AddName extends React.Component {

    ...

    console.log("Props: ", this.props)

    render(){
    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    )

     }

}

mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
      user : state.user
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AddName)
```

hopeit helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function Component so you should use props in this way :

```
const AddName = (props) => {

...

console.log("Props: ", props)

return (
    <>
    ...
    </>
 ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class components instead of the function component.
Read more about that.

https://codeburst.io/react-js-understanding-functional-class-components-e65d723e909